# .NET Core Web API - How to Get Response Information from ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI Core endpoint method where I am using a in-house library (RequestLogManager) to save the request and response data from and incoming request.

*Because I want to log the response code and body*, I am storing the ActionResult in a variable that is returned at the end of the method (instead of returning from multiple locations in the method). Example:

```
    // This is a contrived method to illustrate the issue.
    
    [Route("test/actionresult/{testParam:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetTestActionResult(int testParam)
    {
        ActionResult actionResult = Ok(); // Default

        // Log Incoming Request
        int requestlogid = await RequestLogManager.LogIncomingRequestAsync("API - GetTestActionResult", Request);

        switch (testParam)
        {
            case 204:
                actionResult = NoContent();
                break;

            case 404:
                actionResult = NotFound();
                break;

            case 500:
                actionResult = StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An Error Occurred!");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        // Log Outgoing Response
        RequestLogManager.LogResponseForRequestNoWait(requestlogid, ??? ResponseBody ???, ??? ResponseCode ???);

        return actionResult;
    }
```

At the end of my method, how can I get the value for the response code and body from ActionResult to log?

- I tried using Response.Body and Response.StatusCode, but those are always "" and 200 (I presume because I'm using ActionResult and not actually creating an HttpResponse).
- I tried casting ActionResult to ObjectResult - ObjectResult does have those in properties StatusCode and Value - but that results in an error message: `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NoContentResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult'`

Comment: Read up on action filters and middleware, which is where these cross cutting concerns should be handled. Not in the controller action

Comment: You just want the status code and the response, just build both of them, then at the end of the method do `return StatusCode(statusCode, theMessageToReture);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware are the way to go to handle request and response logging. You can your custom middleware and they can be hooked to the `HTTP` pipeline and you can perform the logging within the middleware implementations. This approach helps you do it globally.

#### Creating middleware for your intercepting your requests and responses

```
// Request Logging middleware
public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    public RequestLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Logic to log your request. Can be accessed via "context.Request"
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

```
// Response Logging Middleware
public class ResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    public ResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // observe the Invoke() method being called first
        await _next.Invoke(context)
        // This is where your logging logic goes. For eg., you can capture 404 as below
        if(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            // log the 404 and do whatever you want to do on a 404 here.
        }
    }
}
```

#### Hooking up the middleware to `HTTP` pipeline

This is pretty straightforward and done with the below statements of code.

```
// Within the Configure() method of Startup.cs
app.UseMiddleware<ResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
```

The order in which you are hooking up the middleware matters here. More information on middleware ordering and middleware in general [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order)

Update:

#### Creating custom attribute to handle logging at endpoint level

```
public class LoggingAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // This method is called just right after the completion of the 
        // execution of the action method. Status Code can be obtained as shown below
        // response logging based on status code goes here.
        var result = context.Result;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // This method is called before the action method is invoked.
        // Access the request using context.HttpContext.Request
        // and include the logging logic where
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;            
    }
}
```

This attribute can now be added to your action method inside your controller wherever required as shown below.

```
[HttpGet]
[LoggingAttribute]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    // ...other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sai, thanks for the great example code. How would I implement this if I only wanted to add logging to certain endpoints?

Comment: If you want to do that to certain endpoints only, Filters are your friends. Will put up sample code to do that in a while now.

Comment: @JeffofNewOcean, did this address your query?

Comment: this is perfect for my needs. Thanks! (I'm new to stackoverflow; it won't let me upvote  yet)

Comment: How i can get the context.Request.Body in the Invoke of the Middleware?